# Crystal Rreports: Mention computer name which generates it

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Is there a way to mention the current Computer's Name from which the report is generated on crystal report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the following name space and code get the current computer's name and pass it as an parameter to the crystal report

```
using System.Security.Principal;

WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes that's achievable, but I was looking for if Crystal Report has an in-build formula or a function for it.

Comment: Marshal, I have done somany projects basing Crystal Reports, but up to my knowledge. There's no in-build formula or a function to get the Computer name in Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1):

Try [U2lwin32 UFL](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/u2lwin32.htm)